# What is api interception? when is it used? how to implement it in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is API interception

When is it used

How to implement it in C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API interception is intercepting calls to a given DLL and re-directing them through your code.

It is generally used to override some functionality provided by a DLL.  An example is for adding a logo to a DirectX based game.

How to implement it?  Thats a complicated one and it depends on what sort of DLL you are trying to intercept.  You may want do look around here and the net about "DLL Injection" or "API hooking".

e.g ['Safe' DLL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764980/safe-dll-injection)
or http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/hooksys.aspx